# Better way to display posts from specific categories, in a grid layout

Tags: loop, query-posts, homepage

I'm using the following code to display posts from a specific category, in a grid layout, on my home page. It works exactly how I want it to, but I keep reading that I shouldn't ever use query_posts. How can I achieve the same results, without using query_posts?

Also, I will eventually need to display posts from maybe ten different categories on the home page - using this exact same grid layout. Would it cause issues if I duplicated all of the code below for each category, or is there a more efficient way to do this?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated - as you will probably be able to work out from my code and questions, I'm fairly new to WordPress development :)

```
<?php
$counter = 1; //start counter
$grids = 3; //Grids per row
global $query_string; //Need this to make pagination work

/*Setting up our custom query (In here we are setting it to show 3 posts per page and eliminate all sticky posts) */
query_posts( array('posts_per_page'=>3, 'category_name'=>'Mobile') );

if(have_posts()) :  while(have_posts()) :  the_post(); 
?>

<?php
//Show the left hand side column
if($counter == 1 || $counter == 2) :
?>
            <div class="col-cat3">
                <div class="entry-featured"><?php x_featured_image(); ?></div>
                <div class="col-cat-pic"><?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta('ID'), 40); ?></div>
                <div class="hero-info">
                <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                <p class="p-meta"><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>  /  <?php the_time('m.d.y'); ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
<?php
//Show the right hand side column
elseif($counter == $grids) :
?>
             <div class="col-cat3-last">
                <div class="entry-featured"><?php x_featured_image(); ?></div>
                <div class="col-cat-pic"><?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta('ID'), 40); ?></div>
                <div class="hero-info">
                <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                <p class="p-meta"><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>  /  <?php the_time('m.d.y'); ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
<?php
$counter = 0;
endif;
?>
<?php
$counter++;
endwhile;
//Pagination can go here if you want it.
endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the general suggestion is to use `WP_Query` instead of `query_posts` partly because query_posts used WP_query in a simplified way and can cause problems down the road. So for sure **check out the WP_Query page, specifically the Multiple Loops example**: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Multiple_Loops

So the code using `WP_Query` would look something like this:

```
<?php
$counter = 1; //start counter
$grids = 3; //Grids per row
global $query_string; //Need this to make pagination work

/*Setting up our custom query (In here we are setting it to show 3 posts per page and eliminate all sticky posts) */
$query1 = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page'=>3, 'category_name'=>'Mobile') );

if( $query1->have_posts()) :  while( $query1->have_posts()) : $query1->the_post(); 

    if( $counter == $grids ) : 
        $counter = 0; // Reset counter ?>
        <div class="col-cat3-last">
    <?php else: ?>
        <div class="col-cat3">
    <?php endif; ?>

        <div class="entry-featured"><?php x_featured_image(); ?></div>
        <div class="col-cat-pic"><?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta('ID'), 40); ?></div>
            <div class="hero-info">
                <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                <p class="p-meta"><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>  /  <?php the_time('m.d.y'); ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php
$counter++;
endwhile;
//Pagination can go here if you want it.
endif;
wp_reset_postdata(); // Reset post_data after each loop
?>
```

Notice the same `$args` can be used in the WP_Query. Also notice the addition of `$query1->` in the loop setup. Just change $query1 to $query2 when you copy paste this code and most likely change the category_name in the query args to match your category.

I also cleaned up some repetative code as it looked like the only difference was the '-last' added to the wrapping div class. So instead of having extra code to update in the future you could just use this.

I also added `wp_reset_postdata();` in the end there to be safe and clear/reset the post data.

Let me know if you have any questions or concerns.

Comment: Thanks for that Sean, works perfectly. Hope you don't mind me asking a follow up question. If I wanted to use that same layout for my category page, what would I need to change? At the moment my category page shows all the posts - not just the category you click through from.

Comment: Yeah, No prob. ... If you wanted to use this same layout for a Category Page just remove the WP_Query line completly and the `$query1->` from in front of the 2 have_posts() and the_post() (this makes it like a regular loop... ie http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Loop_Examples ) ... remove the `wp_reset_postdata()` at the bottom and the `global query_string` at the top. Then I'd suggest to save it as category.php if you don't already have one. ... Also check out this page: http://wphierarchy.com/ and follow the Archive Page -> Category Page to see what your theme is using for Category Page.

Comment: Fantastic - thanks again! I saved it as category.php as recommended, and will definitely check out the links you provided.